# PHP Concatenate Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a php concatenate problem for echoing Bootstrap Glyphicon.

The HTML for Bootstrap Glyphicon is:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

I want to concatenate for PHP echo so I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
echo "<p>" . "<span class=" . "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" . "aria-hidden=" . "true" . ">" . "</span>" . $row['id'] . "</p>";
```

Comment: try replacing `"glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"` with `'"glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"'` (notice the single quote marks). Basically your current code will produce HTML like this `<span class=glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker aria-hidden=true></span>` which is missing quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ,

```
<?php echo '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true">'.$row['id'].'</span></p>';?>
```